# How do you share a MS Access Database File in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a MS Access file for data logging in my C# project but when the system is open and another remote workstation wants to access this MS Access file, it notifies that you cannot access that file because it is already in use? Can this be programmed in C# that this MS Access file can be shared to another workstation?
Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;

using System.Security.AccessControl;


using ADOX;

namespace TestDataLog
{
    public class TestDataLog
    {
        OleDbConnection dbConnection = null;

        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder oleDbConnectionStringBuilder = null;

        OleDbCommand command;

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public string TableName { get; set; }


        public TestDataLog(string tableName, string path, string fileName = "TestDataLog.Mdb")
        {
            try
            {
                TableName = tableName;

                FileName = fileName;

                dbConnection = new OleDbConnection();

                oleDbConnectionStringBuilder =

                new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();

                oleDbConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";

                path = Path.Combine(path, FileName);

                oleDbConnectionStringBuilder.DataSource = path;

                oleDbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString += ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5";

                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    Catalog catalog = new Catalog();

                   catalog.Create(oleDbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
                }

                this.Open();

                this.CreateTable();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Close();

                throw ex;
            }                        
        }


        public void Log(string serial, bool testResult)
        {
            try
            {
                command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();

                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + TableName +
                    " (DateTimeLog," +
                    " SN," +
                    " TestResult)" +
                    " VALUES(#" +
                    DateTime.Now + "#, '" +
                    serial + "', " +
                    testResult + ")";

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                this.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Close();

                throw ex;               
            }
        }


        public void Open()
        {
            if (!(dbConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open))
            {
                dbConnection.ConnectionString =
                    oleDbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;

                dbConnection.Open();
            }
        }



        public void Close()
        {
            if (dbConnection != null)
                if (!(dbConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed))
                {
                    dbConnection.Close();

                    dbConnection = null;
                }
        }


        public void CreateTable()
        {
            try
            {
                command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();

                command.CommandText =
                    "CREATE TABLE " + TableName + " (" +
                    "[Count] IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    "[DateTimeLog] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, " +
                    "[SN] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                    "[TestResult] BIT NOT NULL)";

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                if (!(ex.Message.StartsWith("Table") && ex.Message.EndsWith("already exists.")))
                {
                    this.Close();

                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using Access instead of something like SQL Server Express?

Comment: Perhaps because you can be pretty much guaranteed that Jet is installed on any Windows computer, because it is part of the Windows installation, and that is what this code is using, Jet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Mode=Share Deny None` to your connection string. This will open your database file in full share mode. Now it's up to you to manage concurrency, though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Of Course Yes.
..Just make sure that your database is placed in a shared folder that other workstation can also view via Network. Then use the file path where your DB is located like:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\MySharedFolder\\TestDataLog.Mdb
```

[MS ACESS Connection](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access)

Regards..